# How can I get someone to checkout as soon as they add a product to cart?

Tags: plugins

Take a look at http://www.passgotutoring.com/shop/product-category/ucla/ucla-14a/ and add a product.

I would like it to go directly to checkout as soon as anything is added to cart.

Ideas on how to make this happen?

Shopping cart: Woocommerce

Comment: It depends. What shopping cart plugin are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is included on the product page and can be enabled in:

WooCommerce => Settings => Catalog => Catalog Options => Redirect to cart after adding a product to the cart (on single product pages)

But to accomplish this on the category page would more than likely require modifying the filter/hook within WooCommerce. Or customizing the content-product_cat.php file and it's related files.

Take a look at http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/codex/template-structure/ for the guide to customizing the theme/pages.